# Posting image in facebook fan page using c#

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms

I wish to post image on my Facebook fan page with a winform application, but the code doesn't work. `FacebookOAuthException` error was occur. Anyone know how to handle this problem?

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = txtMessage.Text;
        parameters.access_token = _accessToken;
        parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject
        {
            ContentType = "image/jpeg",
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName)
        }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName));

        FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);

var result = app.Post("/" + [page id] + "/feed", parameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to replace this line

> var result = app.Post("/" + [page id] + "/feed", parameters);

by

> var result = app.Post("/" + [Album id] + "/feed", parameters);

to get album Id you can get from

> 

```
        string AlbumId;
        dynamic albums = app.Get("me/albums");
        foreach (dynamic albumInfo in albums.data)
        {
          if( albumInfo.name == "Timeline Photos" ) AlbumId=albumInfo.id; break;
        }
```