# Trying to post photos to Facebook using Facebook C# SDK returns exception "Facebook.FacebookOAuthException"

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to upload photo to a page I have created. Unfortunately it returns me the following exception - `A first chance exception of type 'Facebook.FacebookOAuthException' occurred in Facebook.dll`.

You'd think that I have missed some permission in the "Graph API Explorer", but I have actually checked every single one of them and I am using that Access Token. Obviously the problem is connected to the Access Token, but I am not sure how.

Here is what I have tested and it works fine:

- Posting messages on my personal wall
- Posting photos in my personal album
- Posting messages on my page

And yet when I try to post photos to my page album or to my page wall it returns me that exception.

I use the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494154/posting-image-in-facebook-fan-page-using-c-sharp?rq=1):

```
            FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.access_token = accessToken;
            parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject           
            {
                FileName = "My_Picture.jpg",     
                ContentType = "image/jpeg"
            }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(@"F:\\My_Picture.jpg"));

            //"my" album ID is 12345
            //page album id is 67890
            facebookClient.Post("/67890/photos", parameters);
```

I have tried changing `/photos` to `/feed`, but it doesn't work either. I have also tried changing the `67890` (album ID) with my page name and page id.

I use VS 2013, C# with WPF, newest version of Facebook SDK C#.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I reset the permissions and now everything works properly*.

*What I was looking for was posting the photo on the page **as** the page. Right now the code above posts a photo on the page as a normal user.

Comment: How did you restart it ?

Comment: @MTo you do not 'restart' anything - you have (had?) to reset the settings. Change to default and then change them as needed. Reverting the settings to the default ones is not required if you can figure out what exactly you need to change. This answer may or may not be helpful as it has been more than a year and I haven't touched the Facebook API in a while.

Comment: I found in the meantime that One must set status_update permission and it will work :D